# Hugo: Static files not found after running "hugo import jekyll"

Tags: jekyll, hugo

After running `hugo import jekyll`, everything seems to be working fine except for the images. I'm running it locally through `hugo server -D`.

Inside `blogpost1.md` that lives in `content/post`, I have an image with the path:

`![stage]({{ site.url }}/assets/img/2018/SIS2018.jpg)`

That I changed to the following as per Hugo docs:

`![stage](/assets/img/2018/SIS2018.jpg)`

Following is the folder structure:

```
|_ content
|___ post
|_____ blogpost1.md
|_ static
|____ assets
|_______ img
|_________ 2018
|___________ SIS2018.jpg
```

And `config.toml` file that I have yet to touch:

```
baseURL = "http://example.org/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "My New Hugo Site"
theme = "ananke"
```

I also tried changing it to plain HTML but I'm still getting a 404:

```
<img src="/static/assets/img/2018/SIS2018.JPG" title="image title" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my setup everything is working fine using the following code + structure:

**{{ .Site.BaseURL }}img/posts/image.png** (you can omit the {{ .Site.BaseURL }} part if relative paths are fine)

- My image is located in *static/img/posts/image.png*
- My post is located in *content/posts/post.md*

So you could try to remove the leading slash when using `![stage](/assets/img/2018/SIS2018.jpg)` *(use assets/img/2018/SIS2018.jpg instead of /assets/img/2018/SIS2018.jpg)*

For the plain HTML part `<img src="assets/img/2018/SIS2018.JPG" title="image title" />` should work.